# Using other Lithium based batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry

My question pertains to different types of the Li-ion batteries currently available.

http://investingnews.com/daily/resource-investing/energy-investing/lithium-investing/6-types-of-lithium-ion-batteries/

Many of them address relevantl issues which are generally faced with the current type of Li-ion used in everyday electronics, probably the Li cobalt based battery.

Like Li-manganese based cells which are considered thermally stable than most other types or Li-NMC which in my opinion should become the battery type of choice to be used for everyday electronics, having better energy density, longer life and obviously safe. *(It even has the same nominal voltage and cut-off power, can be replaced?)*

Obviously, these may not be revolutionary in its ultimate objective, but it definitely is better than the current choice used, considering even that was used to replace the erstwhile Ni-Mh based batteries as, only, a better upgrade after all.

So technically speaking, why isn't Li-NMC, for eg, not being used in laptops or smartdevices, etc? Is there something else missing, in the engineering choice of it?

*PS - Not referring to the cost or industry adoption rate, etc*

Comment: You may not be referring to the cost, but it is a huge factor regardless.

Comment: That is true, but there is one more truth about cost - it decreases with rapid use. I can get LI-NMC for maybe 50% more than the usual ones, which is not much if you work in volumes.

Comment: Yes, but the decrease is on a FCFS basis.

Comment: That is true in a lot of scenarios. The main thing which I could not understand was if there are better alternatives, there should be a reason to use it. For Li-NMC, for eg, if I am using it in a project without even replacing the Li-baterry management ICs, it is obviously a benefit, in terms of end usage. Cost can be then overcomed gradually. Other than cost, is there any engg specific issue I should also look into. None I can find for NMC.
For Titanate I can assume, yes, because the entire power system would have to be changed and it can be costly.
Similar with others.

Answer (score 2):

Besides (but related to) cost, you must consider availability. While you can buy a few of them easily enough, batteries of new technologies take time to reach mainstream usage because it takes time to get the production up to the millions/day demand level of mainstream use.